# Autocompletion broken after loading certain module

Tags: python, auto-complete-mode, elpy

I'm using Emacs (GNU Emacs 26.1 (build 1, x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.22.30)
of 2019-05-11) on CentOS 8 and want to use autocompletion when coding with python.

```
Emacs.............: 26.1
Elpy..............: 1.35.0
Virtualenv........: None
Interactive Python: python3.8 3.8.6 (/usr/bin/python3.8)
RPC virtualenv....: rpc-venv (/home/user/.emacs.d/elpy/rpc-venv)
 Python...........: python3.8 3.8.6 (/home/user/.emacs.d/elpy/rpc-venv/bin/python3.8)
 Jedi.............: 0.18.0
 Rope.............: 0.19.0
 Autopep8.........: 1.5.7
 Yapf.............: 0.31.0
 Black............: 21.7b0
Syntax checker....: flake8 (/usr/bin/flake8)
```

Usually, after importing a module and writing its name, if I press `<TAB>`, then a buffer called `*Completions*` opens and I can see possible completions:

[image]

However, after loading a certain module of [pyNastran](https://github.com/SteveDoyle2/pyNastran/) (pyNastran.bdf.bdf), autocompletion is broken. Not only for this module but for all others too. For example, if I import numpy with `import numpy as np` and press `<TAB>` after writing `np.`, then the first possible completion in alphabetical order is autocompleted followed by the characters `^[[0m`. The buffer `*Completions*` does not open at all.

[image]

What could be the reason? How can I try to fix it?

Comment: I'm wrangling auto-completion issues in python-mode as well. Among many findings I noticed `anaconda-mode` halts yasnippets in company.

Comment: Note that the characters `^[[0m` (when `^[` is an escape character) is the ansi escape code for resetting colours (or other styles) in a terminal, so something is likely trying to use colours, and it may be catching your python repl off guard.  Does `C-h v ansi-color-for-comint-mode` help?

Comment: @phils In my case it's set to true, but if I set it to `nil` the error still appears. I don't know how autocompletion-mode works, but I don't understand how can a certain module affect the autocompletion of different ones. Can it be that there is some non-standard character in some file of the imported module, which is then written to an autocompletion lists which therefore breaks autocomplete? I don't even know how to start debugging. I tried it on a different computer with Debian and a newer version of emacs and the error is still there. @jjk Same error with`anaconda-mode` instead of `elpy`

Comment: I don't use python or autocompletion-mode so I have no insight into that side of things; but again, the "non-standard character" appears to be an attempt to generate fancy text in the terminal.  I would firstly look at the documentation for whichever programs you are using to see if there's a way to tell it not to use colour or other ansi escape codes / terminal effects.